# Scala's TreeSet `min` operation performance

Tags: scala, scala-collections

When exploring Scala's standard library, I found out, that `TreeSet` doesn't override `min` operation at all, so this operation is derived from `TraversableOnce` trait, which just uses `reduceLeft`. So I assume it just scans the whole collection, making it a linear complexity operation, even though `TreeSet`'s nature is that its `head` will be the minimum element. But [official Scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) claims its complexity to be O(log n), which would make sense, because all it needs is to traverse the tree to its leftmost element.

So the question is: am I right in assuming `head` will always return the minimum element (according to ordering, of course), and is `min` operation actually a linear operation, thus making official Scala docs incorrect?

Comment: I think you are right. The `min` method appears to be implemented so because it can be given a different ordering: its full signature is `def min[B >: A](implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A`.

Comment: @dkim hmmm makes sense. It's weird though that `TreeSet` doesn't provide any alternative to `min`, one would think it's one of its major functionalities.